Can I see the docstrings of a type (or class) when hovering above an assigned or instantiated variable in vs-code?
I would like to see the documentations of types when hovering over a variable.
For example
M = Literal[3]
N = Literal[2]
MxN = np.ndarray[tuple[M,N], np.dtype[np.int32]]
"""
A type for an MxN matrix
"""
A_MxN: MxN

Leads to:


But can I display the documentation on variable hover, too?
Is there an editor like vs-code or pycharm or a plugin/extension which supports that? If so, how can I enable it?

That' s not really a docstring, which is something that modules, classes, and functions have.

What else is it? But the same example also applies to classes where the class docstring is not shown on the hover

It's just an expression statement consisting of a string literal. It's not treated any differently from any other non-docstring statement. A docstring is specifically a string literal used as the first statement in a module, class, or function definition, which gets used to set the __doc__ attribute of the respective object.

Alright, I removed the term docstring. Bit the question about the display of documentation remains...
